# Looking for a program to work with .pro files

Tags: windows

I am a newbie to Ubuntu and was wondering if someone can help me find a program that will open a .pro file.  I was using Punch Home and Landscape Software in Windows.  Thank you

Comment: Note to potential answerers: The OP is talking about home design software, not QMake project files.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you'll find a linux program to open these files, your best best if you still want your machine to be booted in Linux would be to run Windows in a virtual machine.

Comment: I don't know personally about `.pro` files. However this answer is useless and wildly incorrect. I have yet to come across **anything** that can be done on windows, that cannot done with some open sourced software for linux and not on a virtual machine or emulator (barring playnig some triple-A titled games)